# Nested IF statement returning false

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a nested if statement is returning  "False" rather than the expected outcome.

**Scenario**

Table "High VoltageCables" has data in it that default to numeric but may contain characters: *kVa*

Table "Master" checks "High VoltageCables" data as blank or not blank, and returns "Failed Check 1","Passed Check 1". This works fine.

Table "Meta" then checks the results of "Master" and then tests "High VoltageCables" data for length between 1 and 6, *regardless of whether record is numeric or string.*

**Formula**

```
=IF(MASTER!H2="Passed Check 1",IF(LEN('High VoltageCables'!O2)>=1,IF(LEN('High VoltageCables'!O2<6),"Passed Check 2","Failed Check 2")))
```

This is partially succesful, as it returns "Passed Check 2" for the following sample data in the source table "High VoltageCables".

1             *numeric,* or

1kVa          *str,* or

50000         *numeric*

However if a field in "High VoltageCables"is blank, the formula returns "FALSE" rather than "Failed Check 1"

I inherited this task, (and would have preferred to do the whole thing in Access using relatively simple queries) - and unfortunately I am new to nested If statements, so I am probably missing something basic...

NB the data in High VoltageCables *must* default to numeric for a further check to work.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second IF's seem to be missing the else part. They should be added at the end between the ))) like ), else ), else )
Every IF statement consists of IF( condition, truepart, falsepart) if you have two nested ifs it will be something like IF( condition, IF( condition2, truepart2, falsepart2), falsepart)
Hope that makes it a little clearer

Comment: Thank you, but apologies - can you elucidate ?

Answer (score 0):

You do have an unaccounted for FALSE in the middle IF. Try bring the latter two conditions together.

```
=IF(Master!H2="Passed Check 1",IF(OR(LEN('High VoltageCables'!O2)={1,2,3,4,5}),"Passed Check 2","Failed Check 2"))
```

It's still a bit unclear on what to show or not show if Master!H2 does not equal "Passed Check 1".

Comment: Thank you, plese see my reply above - solved thanks to your input.

Comment: [Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I failed to construct the formula with a concluding "else" - "Failed Check 1"

Using *jeeped*'s and *Tom's* suggestion and adding the final "else" part I have solved the problem:

```
=IF(MASTER!H2="Passed Check 1",IF(OR(LEN('High VoltageCables'!O2)={1,2,3,4,5}),"Passed Check 2","Failed Check 2"),"Failed Check 1")
```