# Excel Syntax "False" Error

Tags: excel

```
= IF(
    H2="Sandy loom",
    IF(
        AND(H1>=0,H1<=10),
        D2,
        IF(
            AND(H1>10,H1<=100),
            D3,
            IF(
                H2="sandy",
                IF(
                    AND(H1>=0,H1<=10),
                    D2,
                    IF(
                        AND(H1>10,H1<=100),
                        D3,
                        "Check"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This syntax keep returning FALSE when `H2="sandy"`. I want it to execute the other half of the syntax after recognizing `H2="sandy"`.

Comment: Well, there is no _"other half"_ i.e. else clause of that `if`, so what do you expect? This shows how a bit of whitespace helps to understand what code is actually doing. Shame Excel doesn't really support that at all... or a `switch` statement yet, so people could post something other than barely comprehensible masses if nested `if`s.

Comment: @urfusion If you don't know, don't post. It's not.

Comment: _"standard programming"_ is hilarious to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested IF statement returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650572/nested-if-statement-returning-false)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, works for me.

```
=IF(H2="Sandy loom",IF(AND(H1>=0,H1<=10),D2,IF(AND(H1>10,H1<=100),D3)),IF(H2="sandy",IF(AND(H1>=0,H1<=10),D2,IF(AND(H1>10,H1<=100),D3,"Check"))))
```

When doing large if's like this, it helps to break them down to manageable pieces.

It is much easier to combine these two than to create one large one in one go.

```
=IF(H2="Sandy loom",IF(AND(H1>=0,H1<=10),D2,IF(AND(H1>10,H1<=100),D3)))

=IF(H2="sandy",IF(AND(H1>=0,H1<=10),D2,IF(AND(H1>10,H1<=100),D3,"Check")))
```

The three brackets closing the first half are closing 3 different if formulas.  If you want the second half to be an if to:

```
IF(H2="Sandy loom"
```

Then you need to place your second half in front of the last bracket in the first half, and then move that last bracket to the end of the entire formula.

```
=IF(H2="Sandy loom",IF(AND(H1>=0,H1<=10),D2,IF(AND(H1>10,H1<=100),D3))XXX)
```

Your second half needs to go where the XXX is located here, then its becomes the false of your first IF.